# Receive POST HTTP request in java

Tags: java, html, sockets

I am creating a multi-threadrd web server (e.g. local host:http://127.0.0.1) in Java.
My question is, how I can read POST request HTTP/1.1 from clients at web server?

Following code works for GET request, but I am wondering how I can get the attributes in POST request:

```
void get(Socket socket) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    if (buffer[0] == (byte)'G' &&
        buffer[1] == (byte)'E' &&
        buffer[2] == (byte)'T' &&
        buffer[3] == (byte)' ') {
    //READ FOLLOWING OF ? in header EX: Get /?ABC=XYZ 
    }
}
```

Comment: i am afraid you'll need to read the spec of http protocal

Comment: I'd recommend not rolling your own. Use [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) or something similar instead.

Answer (score 1):

Where is the `buffer` coming from? Consider using (buffered) `socket.getInputStream()` and reading byte-by-byte (actually character by character). Then once you read `GET`/`POST` you can continue reading the rest of the header.

BTW any reason to implement HTTP where so many HTTP servers and servlet containers are available, ready to be embedded? Remember that HTTP is surprisingly complex protocol...